Getting _grecapthca_cfg undefined in windo
I am using module federations in next js and wrapped the component from each module with google-recapthca provider, but on page change, i get _grecaptcha-cfg undefined, any solutions
i tried wrapping each comp with provider and also added provider in _app.tsx
